# Help adding packages to list

Tags: command-line, repository

I want to install [Genie](https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie) on WSL2. To add a new repository it provides these [instructions](https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/) to add the repo source. However I keep hitting this error `bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wsl-transdebian.list: Permission denied`,

The installation instructions says run the following commands in `sudo -s`:

```
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/wsl-transdebian.gpg https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt/wsl-transdebian.gpg

chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/wsl-transdebian.gpg

cat << EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wsl-transdebian.list
deb https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs) main
deb-src https://arkane-systems.github.io/wsl-transdebian/apt/ $(lsb_release -cs) main
EOF

apt update
```

When I run the `cat` command it comes up with a `>` in the terminal. I then enter the deb commands, are these prefixed with `sudo -s` also? I have tried with and without `sudo -s` but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo tee`:

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wsl-transdebian.list
```